# Is the product of generators equal to the generator of the product?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $(X, \mathcal{J})$ and $(Y, \mathcal{F})$ be two measure spaces. Let us assume
that $J$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ which generates $\mathcal{J}$, i.e. $\sigma(J)=\mathcal{J}$. Similarly, assume $\sigma(F)=\mathcal{F}$. Is it always true that
$$
\sigma(J)\times\sigma(F)=\sigma(J\times F)?
$$
Here, $J\times F$ is the set of all cartesian products of sets in $J$ with sets in $F$.

Please note: in the above expression the two product signs mean different things. On the left I am considering the product sigma algebra $\mathcal{J}\times \mathcal{F}$, while on the right I am considering the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the cartesian products of my ``elementary sets.''

Comment: $\sigma(J) \times \sigma(F)$ might not even be a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: It's defined to be the sigma algebra generated by all measurable rectangles.

Comment: Ah right, I'm used to the notation $\sigma(J)\otimes\sigma(F)$ for that purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to show that if $(X_1,\mathcal F_1)$ and $(X_2,\mathcal F_2)$ are two measurable spaces, and $\mathcal C_j$ are collections of subsets generating $\mathcal F_j$ then $$\tag{*}\mathcal F_1\otimes\mathcal F_2\supset\sigma(\mathcal C_1\times\mathcal C_2),$$
where $\mathcal C_1\times\mathcal C_2=\{C_1\times C_2,C_j\in\mathcal C_j\}$. Since $\mathcal C_1\times\mathcal C_2\subset \mathcal F_1\otimes\mathcal F_2$, and $\mathcal F_1\otimes\mathcal F_2$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, we get (*).

The reversed inclusion [do not hold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2598789/sigma-algebra-generator-set-of-product-space).