# Sigma algebra generator set of product space

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X_1, \mathcal{F}_1)$, $(X_2, \mathcal{F}_2)$ be two measure spaces. Suppose $D_i$ is the generator of the $\sigma-$algebra $\mathcal{F}_i$, $i=1, 2$.

Question:(1) Is $D_1\times D_2=\{A\times B: A\in D_1, B\in D_2\}$ a generator of $\mathcal{F}_1\otimes \mathcal{F_2}$?

(2) What if in addition $D_i$ is closed under intersection?

Comment: The interesting question is: *Under what circumstances* is the statement (1) true?

Answer (score 4):

Someone just told me an counterexample:
Let $\Omega=\Omega_1=\Omega_2=\left\{ 1, 2, 3 \right\}$, $D_1=\left\{ \left\{ 1 \right\} \right\}$, $D_2=\left\{ \left\{ 3 \right\} \right\}$, then
\begin{align*}
  \mathcal{F}_1&=\left\{ \Omega, \emptyset, \left\{ 1 \right\}, \left\{ 2, 3 \right\} \right\}, \\
  \mathcal{F}_2&=\left\{ \Omega, \emptyset, \left\{ 3 \right\}, \left\{ 1, 2 \right\} \right\}.
\end{align*}
On the other hand, we have
$D=\left\{ (1, 3) \right\}$, 
$$\sigma\left( D \right)=\left\{ \Omega_1\times \Omega_2, \emptyset, \left\{ (1,3) \right\}, \left\{ (1, 3) \right\}^C \right\}.$$
Notice that $\mathcal{F}_1\otimes \mathcal{F}_2$ contains $\left\{ (2,3), (3 ,3) \right\}$ which is not in $\sigma(D)$.