# Product sigma-algebra generator

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega_1,F_1)$ and $(\Omega_2,F_2)$ be two measurable spaces. Let $G_1$ be a collection of subsets of $\Omega_1$ that generates $F_1$. Let $G_2$ be a collection of subsets of $\Omega_2$ that generates $F_2$. Suppose in addition, that $\Omega_1\in G_1$ and $\Omega_2\in G_2$. Prove that: $$\sigma(\{A\times B:A\in G_1, B\in G_2\})=F_1\otimes F_2.$$

Attempt:

By definition, we have that:; $$F_1\otimes F_2=\sigma(\{C\times D:C\in F_1,D\in F_2\})$$
Observe that $G_1\subseteq F_1$ and $G_2\subseteq F_2$ and so $$\sigma(\{A\times B:A\in G_1, B \in G_2\})\subseteq F_1\otimes F_2 $$
Now pick $C\in F_1$, and note that we can re-express ${C=\bigcap_k\bigcup_n C_{k,n}}$ where either $C_{k,n}\in G_1$ or $C_{k,n}^c\in G_2$. Similarly choose $D=\bigcap_k\bigcup_n D_{k,n}$. Note that $$C\times D=(C\times\Omega_2)\cup(\Omega_1\times D).$$
Now
\begin{align*}
C\times\Omega_2&=\left(\bigcap_k\bigcup_n C_{k,n}\right)\times\Omega_2\\
&=\bigcap_k\bigcup_n (C_{k,n}\times\Omega_2)
\end{align*}
This shows that $C\times\Omega_2\in\sigma(\{A\times B:A\in G_1, B\in G_2\})$, and by symmetry we conclude that $\Omega_1\times D\in\sigma(\{A\times B:A\in G_1, B\in G_2\})$ as well. Since $C\subseteq\Omega_1$ and $D\subseteq\Omega_2$ we get the following when taking union of the above:
$$C\times D\in\sigma(\{A\times B:A\in G_1, B\in G_2\}).$$
This shows that $F_1\otimes F_2\subseteq\sigma(\{A\times B:A\in G_1, B\in G_2\})$, completing the proof.

I am wondering if this is sufficient, or if there are other details that I need to add? (we define product sigma-algebra as the sigma-algebra generated by the rectangles fyi).

Comment: If $G$ generates $F$, how do you get that any $C \in F$ has a representation as $C = \cap_j \cup_k C_{jk}$ with $C_{jk}$ or $C_{jk}^c \in G$?

Comment: For example for the Borel $\sigma-$algebra, $G$ can be $\{(-\infty, a] \mid a \in \mathbb{R}\}$. Then the complement of the inner union can be only an interval. So the complement of $C$ can be atmost a union of intervals. This certainly doesn't cover all of the Borel $\sigma-$ algebra.

Comment: I am using the fact that sigma-algebras are closed under "all" set theoric operations, so thats why I have that union/intersection representation.

Comment: Yes, it is true that your $C = \cap_j \cup_k C_{jk} \in F_1$. It's just that not all $A \in F_1$ can be written in that form in general.

Comment: So how would I go about trying to solve this

Comment: I'll post a sketch.

Answer (score 2):

As you asked in the comments, here is a sketch of a proof:

- Observe that it is enough to show that for $A \in F_1, B \in F_2$, $A \times B \in \sigma(\{C \times D \mid C \in G_1, D \in G_2\}) = F'$ (why?)
- First let's prove that all sets of the form $A \times B$ with $A \in F_1, B \in G_2$ is in $F'$. For that, fix $B \in G_2$. Write $\mathcal{A} = \{X \mid X \times B \in F'\}$, i.e. all sets satisfying the property needed. Prove that:

  > 1. $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma-$algebra.
  > 2. $G_1 \subset \mathcal{A}$

  This will show that all sets $A$ in $F_1$ satisfy $A \times B \in F'$. Since $B$ was arbitrary, we are done with this step.
- In the final step, we use a similar trick to show that $A \times B \in F'$ for all $A \in F_1, B \in F_2$. Fix $A$ in $F_1$, and define $\mathcal{A'} = \{Y \mid A \times Y \in F'\}$, i.e. all sets satisfying the property needed. Prove that:

  > 1. $\mathcal{A'}$ is a $\sigma-$algebra.
  > 2. $G_2 \subset \mathcal{A'}$

  This will show that all sets $B$ in $F_2$ satisfy $A \times B \in F'$. Since $A$ was arbitrary, we are done with the proof.

This is a kind of lifting argument (you bring things from $G_i$ to $F_i$ incrementally) and is standard in problems like this.

Comment: Why is $\mathcal{A}$ closed under compliments? @mriganka I just don't see why $\Omega_1 \times B$ is in $F'$

Comment: I probably wasn't aware of this when I wrote this solution, but this follows from the additional fact in the question that $\Omega_1 \in G_1$. Without this fact, the result is apparently false (sigma algebra generated by product of generators of two sigma algebras is *not equal* to the product of the two sigma algebras), see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2598789/sigma-algebra-generator-set-of-product-space

Comment: I think it's important to add that it also suffices if $\Omega_1$ is the union of countable many elements from $G_1$. And in fact the same problem arises for $\Omega_2$, where the same requirements are needed.